# How can I make the node order for references in TikZ not matter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

## Question

I am wondering if it is possible to make the order of nodes irrelevant, such that references work regardless of when they are mentioned...like some kind of pre-parsing of the code that creates list of all node labels.

### Sample Code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[left=1cm of server] (client) {Client};
    \node (server) at (0,0) {Server};
    \node[right=1cm of server] (datastorage) {Data Storage};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Issue

The code above will not work, because the first node references a node that has not been created/instantiated yet. Is there a way to make the order not matter?

---

### Why?

The reason for this is that it is easier to have my code mimic my complex diagram's workflow. (irrelevant to the question: I want to have an answer even if you find my reasoning illogical)

Comment: TikZ doesn't do two pass parsing. So it would be a no. But you can use chains effectively for start/pause/resume chains and build up sequentially  different parts of the diagrams.

Comment: How would you resolve two node which are each placed to the left of the other?

Comment: Why not start with `client` and put `server` to its right? Then you have the order you want without needing to reference any node before creating it. Technically, you could reference the node earlier if you used a `tikzmark` to create a sub-node. But this will make your code a lot more complex, introduce an unnecessary source of potential fragility, not to say breakage, and make the code less readable for, as far as I can see, a relatively minor gain (compared to the rather high costs).

Comment: @cfr See my clause "I want to have an answer even if you find my reasoning illogical" :D

Comment: @John Kormylo Exactly! That is another way to word my question! I will include that in my question.

Comment: @macmadness86 I know. But since the answer is 'no', as percusse says, it seemed at least potentially useful to suggest possible workarounds. If the answer was 'yes', it might still be worth mentioning them. Part of what is going on with these sorts of questions in comments is an attempt to figure out what somebody is really trying to do when they seem to want something strange, because often what they really want to do is more easily done in another way. (Known as an XY problem. But these can often only be identified by asking apparently dumb questions.)

Comment: @cfr Well I appreciate your attempt to help. The reason for keeping the server as the origin is because the server is the central unit in many, many diagrams in the manual I am working on. The latex code must be easily readable by multiple people in the event one person is indisposed. The server is naturally the first thing anybody would look for. So in short, for consistency in all drawings. I tend to ask pretty specific questions to address real-world issues. I know I COULD make the client the origin, but it makes my code less universally applicable :(

Comment: Fair enough. You should probably ask @percusse to write an answer since the first comment is the answer to your question, albeit it not the one you hoped for :(. But `chains` should help.

Comment: @percusse care to answer?